# Необходимость typename в глобальной функции и функции-члене

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, language-lawyer, typename

```
template <class T>
T f(T::X x);

template <class T>
struct A {
  T f(T::X x);
};
```

Почему первая функция не компилируется без `typename`, а вторая компилируется https://godbolt.org/z/5x7r8WfGs?

> error: expected ')' before 'x'

Comment: за что минус вопросу?

Answer (score 3):

Это [нововведение C++20](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0634r3.html), необязательный `typename` в некоторых местах (где и так понятно, что это тип). В том числе необязательный в типах параметров функций-членов, но не глобальных функций.

Обратите внимание, что если бы какой-то компилятор не выдавал ошибку на вашем коде (в первом случае, или во втором до С++20), то это не было бы багом, потому что от компилятора не требуется проверять [неинстанцированные шаблоны](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp#res.general-6.1).

Comment: А чем глобальная функция хуже метода? Там же тоже не может быть ничего кроме типа в этом месте.

Comment: @Qwertiy Хз. Видимо потому что сложно отличить от переменной (внутри класса у переменных не бывает инициализаторов с круглыми скобками). Хотя в этом случае отличить можно (по имени параметра), видимо решили не усложнять правила слишком сильно.

Comment: Хм.. А может потому что имя параметра можно опускать? И тогда для консистентности, чтобы в обоих случаях был typename?

Comment: Стоп. А переменные вообще бывают шаблонными? Разве там может быть что-то кроме функции?

Comment: @Qwertiy Бывают, в C++14 подвезли.

Comment: Ой.. Не видел. А как ими пользоваться?

Comment: @Qwertiy Не знаю как объяснить, они работают ровно так как я ожидал. :) Гуглите...

Comment: Ага, разобрался. Странная штука)

Answer (score 1):

Компилятору не известен тип `T::X`. Вот если вы напишете `typename T::X`, то это будет подсказкой, что  эта функция принимает в аргумент именно такой тип, а потом вы увидите, что  вторая функция тоже не компилируется. Не сообщать же вам о той же самой ошибки два раза... Наверняка ваш вопрос стал для кого то плохим за то, что вы уже получили от компилятора сообщение.

P.S. Правильно заметил пользователь `Qwertiy`, что  ответ лучше дополнить для полного введения ясности:

Нам известно, что С++, это язык строгой типизации. По этой причине, компиляторы С++ всегда должны иметь возможность однозначно определить синтаксический смысл каждой инструкции **на ранней стадии** трансляции шаблона(первая фаза). Пока не известны параметры шаблона(шаблон не инстанцирован), природа  зависимых имен неизвестна. А в контексте `T::X`, квалифицированное имя `X`является зависимым именем,и не известно  что она из себя представляет. Из за этого могут возникать не разрешимые неоднозначности. Такого рода неоднозначности, разрешаются при помощи явного указания ключевого слова `typename` точно также, как и  для шаблонной функции члена нужно указать, что это имя шаблона. Например:

```
A::template foo<>();
```

Теперь о том, почему **некоторые компиляторы могут** нормально воспринять:

```
template <class T>
struct A {
  T f(T::X x);
};
```

**без указания typename**:

Старые версии компилятора `MSVC`, двухфазный поиск имен реализовали иначе(не правильно), и для них такая запись не означала возможное возникновение проблем с неоднозначностью. Поэтому эти компиляторы(их "производные"), **могли пропустить вышеуказанный код**. Но по мере столкновения с проблемами, дефект убрали.

**Но** тут есть еще и другой момент. В примере со структурой, очевидно, что `f` является функцией_членом, и не может  принимать в аргумент не тип. Поэтому в `С++20` для подобных случаев сделали **исключение**, и можно не указывать ключевое слово.

А вот в примере:

```
template <class T>
T f(T::X x);
```

это может вполне быть определение объекта, получающее значение T::X x, но тогда не понятно что из себя представляет это выражение, поэтому возникает неоднозначность.

Чтобы избежать непереносимости кода и для уверенности _ лучше написать  ключевое слово для квалифицированных имен. Также, как и лучше написать скобки вокруг, когда не уверены в приоритетах операций.

Comment: Где вторая не компилируется? https://godbolt.org/z/eoP54dKfb - всё компилируется отлично.

Comment: @Qwertiy,  А вот что говорит другой компилятор: warning C4346: 'T::X': dependent name is not a type    error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'X'

Comment: странно. В любом случае, у тебя ошибка какая-то внятная, а не то, что ожидалась скобка. Ну и надо бы рассказать, почему так происходит.

Comment: С удовольствием прочитаю)

Comment: @Qwertiy, спасибо за замечание, я дописал ответ.

Comment: Ага, прочитал. Немного не понял момент про "могли пропустить" - что там было?

Comment: @Qwertiy, имеется ввиду, что могли воспринять как нормальный, компилируемый код.